# Jayway "set" method: how to know if field was missing?

Tags: java, jsonpath

The method `set` of Jayway (implantation of JsonPath)  can be used to set a value at a given path.

The issue I have is that if the value / array index doesn't exist already, no value is changed and no error is given.

This makes it hard to debug as an incorrect entry will do nothing and throw no exception.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that an error is returned?